# Is there any reason not to sell money pins?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

In the original *The World Ends With You*, it was often worth holding on to a few money pins instead of selling them, as they were needed to trade for certain quest items. I was following the same plan in *NEO: The World Ends With You* until I saw there was an unlockable ability called "ShibuPay Autoload" that automatically sells money pins as soon as you get them.

Is there any reason to hold on to money pins in *NEO: TWEWY*? Or are they safe to sell immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the original *TWEWY*, there are no trades in *NEO: TWEWY* that require money pins. With that said, ShibuPay Autoload cannot be disabled once unlocked, resulting in a few reasons you might want to avoid unlocking it.

- Later in the game, you can unlock social links with ShibuPay Bonus, which allows you to earn 5% more money when selling pins. These can be unlocked during Week 3 Day 2 and Week 3 Day 4.
- [According to Chronocidal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/388219/is-there-any-reason-not-to-sell-money-pins/389803?noredirect=1#comment548269_389803), ShibuPay Autoload will continue even if your wallet is full, leading to wasted money. (I haven't been able to test this myself).
- The autosell can make it difficult if you want to keep one copy of each pin in your inventory. However, it doesn't affect yen pins collected before unlocking the ability.

Aside from the first point about waiting until ShibuPay Bonus is unlocked, I haven't found any reason to avoid selling money pins.

Comment: Reason 3: ShibuPay Autoload will continue even if your wallet is full (99,999¥ at first, 999,999¥ after the first Wallet Extension, and 9,999,999¥ after the second) and waste the money.  As such: if you are playing slowly, seeking out every Noise, Thread, Food and Pin you can each day, then you may benefit from keeping up to 99 of each Yen pin in reserve as "extra funds" early in the game.

Comment: @Chronocidal I've added your point to my answer. I had read elsewhere that Autoload wouldn't apply when your wallet was full, but I have not tested it myself.